# What should my next.config.js file look like when exporting static HTML and using next-sass plugin?

Tags: javascript, module, next.js

I am trying to render my Next.js site to static HTML, but I don't know how to add both `exportPathMap` and the next-sass plugin to `module.exports`.

Here is my current next.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  exportPathMap: async function (defaultPathMap) {
    return {
      '/': { page: '/' },
      '/releases': { page: '/releases' },
      '/release?=schlagen': { page: '/release', query: { slug: 'schlagen' }},
      '/release?=nicholas-k-pt-1': { page: '/release', query: { slug: 'nicholas-k-pt-1' }},
      '/release?=static-and-shades': { page: '/release', query: { slug: 'static-and-shades' }},
      '/release?=digital-romance': { page: '/release', query: { slug: 'digital-romance' }},
      '/release?=2011': { page: '/release', query: { slug: '2011' }},
      '/artwork': { page: '/artwork' },
      '/artwork/weekend-mixtapes': { page: '/weekendMixtapes' },
      '/artwork/posters': { page: '/posters' }
    }
  }
}

const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass')
module.exports = withSass()
```

How can I add both to my configuration?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation at https://nextjs.org/docs/#customizing-babel-config

> Multiple configurations can be combined together with function
>   composition. For example:

```
module.exports = (phase, {defaultConfig}) => {
    return withSass({
        exportPathMap: ...
    })
}
```